# Byte Order Mark suddenly appearing in query results

Tags: bug, status-completed, json, api-v2.2

Query results seem to have started including BOMs sometime today. I had to add code to handle it.

I don't see this documented anywhere.

Comment: Question needs specifics.  Nevertheless, I checked and something's there (not harming my apps at all).  I get `F7EF F7BB F7BF` though instead of the expected `EF BB BF` (May be a Firefox artifact).  If you fetch the results using the `text/plain` MimeType, it shouldn't be a problem. (Works for me.) *Update:* `application/json` also works for me (BOM auto-handled).

Comment: I've reported this [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235000/186281)

Comment: Issue [resolved on/with Andy's meta.SE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235000/148310).